# Importing Data from Another Worksheet using GetOpenFilename "Default Method of Object Range Failed"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a button that imports data from a user-selected file (last month) to a user-selected file (this month).

I define my variables, and all works well until I get to the actual importing bit, where I set the range from the first workbook equal to the range of the second workbook, I get the following Error:

> Run-time error '1004'
>
> Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed

Both documents have the same number of rows.  Here is the Applicable Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ImportData()
    Dim InputFilename As Variant
    Dim OutputFilename As Variant
    Dim InputFile As Variant
    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim OutputFile As Variant
    Dim OutputSheet As Worksheet

      'Copy data from user-defined sheet to current open sheet
      
      'User selects file to export data from
          InputFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename()
              Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(InputFilename)
              Set InputSheet = InputFile.Sheets("Total Inventory")

      'User defines file to import into
          OutputFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename()
              Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(OutputFilename)
              Set OutputSheet = OutputFile.Sheets("Total Inventory")

Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim UsedRange As Range
Dim LastColumn As Range

  'Find last Row of input file
    InputSheet.Activate
    FirstRow = 7
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 'Find last Column of input file
   Set LastColumn = InputSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _   
                                     after:=InputSheet.Cells(1), _
                                     Searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                     MatchCase:=False)_
                                     .Columns

OutputSheet.Range(OutputSheet.Cells(FirstRow, 2), _
    OutputSheet.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Value = _
InputSheet.Range(InputSheet.Cells(FirstRow, LastColumn), _
    InputSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value

InputFile.Close

End Sub
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LastColumn` is `Range` and causing problem in `Cells(FirstRow, LastColumn)` about `Cells` -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196273(v=office.14).aspx

Try this little modifications:

```
  'Find last Column of input file
   Dim LastColumnNum As Integer
   Set LastColumn = InputSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                     after:=InputSheet.Cells(1), _
                                     Searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                     MatchCase:=False)

    LastColumnNum = LastColumn.Column

OutputSheet.Range(OutputSheet.Cells(FirstRow, 2), _
    OutputSheet.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Value = _
InputSheet.Range(InputSheet.Cells(FirstRow, LastColumnNum), _
    InputSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumnNum)).Value
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem.  I still get an error on the "InputSheet.Range..." line.

Comment: @Meringue90: Check what value have `LastRow` and `LastColumnNum` when an error occurs

Comment: HOLY MACKEREL! IT WORKED!  Thank you!  AMAZING!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ImportData()
Dim InputFilename As String
Dim OutputFilename As String
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Integer

Dim InputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputFile As Workbook
Dim OutputSheet As Worksheet
Dim InputSheet As Worksheet

Dim UsedRange As Range


'Copy data from user-defined sheet to current open sheet

'User selects file to export data from
InputFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set InputFile = Workbooks.Open(InputFilename)
Set InputSheet = InputFile.Sheets("Total Inventory")

'User defines file to import into
OutputFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(OutputFilename)
Set OutputSheet = OutputFile.Sheets("Total Inventory")


'Find last Row of input file
FirstRow = 7
LastRow = InputSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Find last Column of input file
LastColumn = InputSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Copy the data
OutputSheet.Range(OutputSheet.Cells(FirstRow, 2), _
                    OutputSheet.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Value = _
InputSheet.Range(InputSheet.Cells(FirstRow, LastColumn), _
                    InputSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Value

InputFile.Close

End Sub
```

You were inputing a Range into Cells() so it could work

Comment: This is pretty close, it doesn't give me errors, but when I look at the first column of the Output sheet, it is all zeros.  It does not actually copy the data.